# When creating virtual machine in Azure with template Sql Server 2014 SP1 Web on Windows Server 2012 R2, a 1TB premium disk is always attached

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When creating the VM I'm asked about Storage configuration. When I select IOPS=0 (the minimum is otherwise 5000), Throughput=0 and Storage size=0, the info text is

> 0 data disks will be added to the virtual machine. This value was computed based on the value of IOPS, throughput, and storage size.

When the VM is created and I go to the Storage account, select Blobs and Container named vhds I see two disks, one 127GB and one 1TB disk.

Since the 1TB premium disks costs >100€/month I don't want that.

I tried removing the disk from a created machine but when I tried to add a new I got the error that "LUN :0 is already in use".

Preferably I would like to create machine correctly from the start. How can I do that?

Comment: Post this to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: FYI I just tried this and, in the validation, it indeed shows that a 1TB disk will be created in addition to the OS disk. I'd report this through the portal as feedback (as a bug). In any case: This can't really be answered here (or ServerFault).

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The current SQL Server IaaS experience on Azure Portal would creates one disk of 1TB even if specify 0 IOPS. We will add a fix to ensure the user cannot specify IOPS below 1 TB disk. If you need SQLVM without disks or any other configurations, you may use Azure PowerShell to create the VM.

Comment: We want a disk but would rather use a 127GB (P10) disk instead of 1TB (P30) disk. Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: The portal experience creates in multiple of 1TB. You can create a template and run it from PowerShell to do that. You don't have to create the template from scratch.